# authentication with Active Directory using ADFS and Azure MFA

Tags: asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, adfs, multi-factor-authentication

I have an asp.net mvc application.
I am working on the authentication with Active Directory using ADFS and Azure MFA.

While searching, I got few articles to accomplish this requirement, but they are suggesting to redirect the Login page of application to Login page of ADFS and then come back.

Redirecting to ADFS Login page is not suggested as per user experience.

Can anyone help me to find out the solution to authenticate with active directory using ADFS behind the scene ? So, everything will be handled by application code, not by ADFS login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.

In the Microsoft world, the login screen is "outsourced". This is true for ADFS, Azure AD and Azure AD B2C.

To do what you want would require authentication API's that don't exist.